# How can I pass an extra calculated field in a Rails 7 controller response in this context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the following code:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    tasks = current_user.tasks.all.page(params[:page] || 1)

    tasks.each do |task|
      authorize!(:read, task)

      task.merge(total_duration_of_time_entries => task.total_duration_of_time_entries)
    end

    render_data(tasks)
  end
```

How do I add an extra field to the tasks array? I'm trying to add `total_duration_of_time_entries` which is a method in my model..

Comment: What is `render_data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it like this:

```
  def index
    tasks = current_user.tasks.all.page(params[:page] || 1)
    arr = []
    tasks.each do |task|
      authorize!(:read, task)

      extra_fields = { 'folder_name' => task.folder.name,
                       'project_name' => task.folder.project.name,
                       'project_id' => task.folder.project_id,
                       'active_time_entries' => JSON.parse(task.time_entries.where(end_date: nil).all.to_json) }

      arr << JSON.parse(task.to_json).merge(extra_fields)
    end

    render(json: { success: true, data: arr, meta: pagination_info(tasks) }.to_json)
  end
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If it is "standard" rails serialization, you can override [`as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) method in the `Task` model

```rb
def as_json(options = nil)
  super.merge(total_duration_of_time_entries:) # also use value if it is old Ruby
end
```

But it's more flexible to use some serializer (e.g. [blueprinter](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter)) or JSON template generator (e.g. [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder))